# Write to socket quits program

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm writing a basic hello world network program, but when I call `write` in the client the program just stops. Does anyone know why this happens? The function doesn't return anything:

```
const char* msg = "Hello World!\n";
char buffer[256];
int sockfd, n;
struct sockaddr_in srv_ip4;
struct hostent* server;

puts ("a");
sockfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0) {
    perror ("Unable to open socket");
    return false;
}

puts ("b");
server = gethostbyname (addr);
if (!server) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Unable to find host: %s\n", addr);
    return false;
}
memset (&srv_ip4, 0, sizeof (struct sockaddr_in));

puts ("c");
srv_ip4.sin_family = AF_INET;
memcpy (&srv_ip4.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_addr, server->h_length);
srv_ip4.sin_port = htons (PORT);

puts ("d");
n = write (sockfd, msg, 13);
if (n < 0) {
    puts ("Why?");
    perror ("Unable to write to socket");
    return false;
}
memset (buffer, 0, 256);

puts ("e");
n = read (sockfd, buffer, 255);
if (n < 0) {
    perror ("Unable to read from socket");
    return false;
}
printf ("%s", buffer);

puts ("f");
close (sockfd);

return true;
```

The output is:

> a b c d

Comment: Does the program hang or terminate?

Comment: The program terminates.

Comment: Where is 'sockfd' declared and where does it get connected?

Comment: Where is the rest of the program? Please post a complete program that we can run which demonstrates the error, not a snippet.

Comment: What does your debugger say ?

Comment: That's basically the whole program, the code I posted is the function run which takes the server address "addr" as variable.

Comment: tcp protocol needs connect function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should [connect](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/2/connect.htm) to server before sending data.

Via [this article](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm).

Comment: Still, he should get a -1 and an errno. Why doesn't his program print "Why?" and perror?

Comment: I bet somewhere else he has pointer problems and therefore UB